# How is dynamic linker linked when executable using shared library is loaded?

Tags: c++, linker, operating-system

I'm reading about the process of dynamic linking currently, and I read that the dynamic linker is also a shared library(ld.linux.so). Then how is ld.linux.so linked?

Is it linked in a static way?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it linked in a static way?

Yes. It's a shared library which itself has no dependencies on other libraries  (and can't have any, since there is nothing that would resolve such dependencies) -- it must be entirely self-contained.

In particular, `ld.so` contains its own copies of many `libc` routines (`malloc`, `mmap`, `strcpy`, etc.). You can see them with `nm /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (if your distribution doesn't `strip` symbols from `ld-linux`).

Further, this special shared library is `mmap`ed by the kernel at random address, and it must *relocate* itself when it starts (since again, there is nothing else that would perform such relocation).

This self-relocation could be rather involved on platforms which don't allow PC-relative data addressing.

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot. So the ld.so is a static object instead of a dynamic library? Since it has the suffix ".so", I'm afraid not.

Comment: @zkh You can use `file -L /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, which will say `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object`. It _is_ a shared library, just a special one (as described above).

Answer (score -1):

When the kernel loads an excecutable, it looks for the `.interp` section of the ELF file; short for *interpreter*. For dynamically linked executables this will be set to 'ld-linux' by the static linker during build time. During runtime, the kernel loads this interpreter which handles the linking of other libraries.

You can see this using `readelf -p .interp <executable>`. For example, on my system running `readelf -p .interp /bin/ls` outputs

```
String dump of section '.interp':
  [     0]  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

See also the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) for ld-linux.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "how is `ld.so` _itself_ linked" _at all_.

Comment: @EmployedRussian But that wasn't the question. The question was How is dynamic linker linked _when executable using shared library is loaded_? Both our answers explain part of the overall process.